# Fetch data from a WP page with same name as current username

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, username

Ok, so this sounds a little complex, but in theory should be easy.

What I'm trying to achieve:

ACF data is pulled from a WP page which has the same name as the current logged in user.

Basically I will have a WP page set up for each company. I will create a login for each company with an appropriate username. The name of the company page will be the exact same name as the username I create. It will have Advanced Custom Fields entered with data.

I want to dynamically pull in the ACF data from the company page based on the current user logged in into my page template.

So if company A are logged in, I want them to view the custom fields from company A's page. Company B log in and view the custom fields from the company B page.

So far, I have this:

```
    <?php
      global $user_login;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      $username = $current_user->user_login;
      $other_page = $username;
    ?>
    <p><?php the_field('my_custom_field', $other_page); ?></p>
```

Which in theory should work, but it just doesn't.

I can check the current username of the logged in user and echo it which returns the correct username just fine on the page.

I can also add a page ID by adding the page ID like this: `$other_page = 890;` and it pulls in the custom field data from the correct company page (890 being one of the company pages).

So everything works as it should independently, just not when I want to use the logged in username as the name of the page (namely $other_page).

I'm baffled with this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According with [docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/), when you want to retrieve field attached to post using `get_field` / `the_field` you should pass a numeric ID as 2nd argument.

You are passing a string.

So your code *should* work if:

```
$login = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
$page = $login ? get_page_by_path( $login ) : false;
$field = $page ? get_field('my_custom_field', $page->ID) : false;
```

Comment: Hi @PhilOwen, it worked for you?

Comment: No. I couldn't get it working with this.